# How to manually infer that integral result?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

I would like to simplify the formula manually as follows:
$$
\int_0^a{\sin \left( \frac{n\pi}{a}x \right) \frac{1}{x}\sin \left( \frac{m\pi}{a}x \right) dx}
$$
Discuss the cases where **(1)** $n=m$ and **(2)** $n\neq m$, respectively.

The results were obtained by mathematica software:

```
Integrate[1/x*Sin[n*Pi*x/a0] Sin[n*Pi*x/a0], {x, 0, a0}] // FullSimplify
```

> 1/2 (EulerGamma - CosIntegral[2 n \[Pi]] + Log[2 n \[Pi]])

```
Integrate[1/x*Sin[n*Pi*x/a0] Sin[m*Pi*x/a0], {x, 0, a0}] // FullSimplify
```

> 1/2 (CosIntegral[(m - n) \[Pi]] - CosIntegral[(m + n) \[Pi]] -
> Log[m - n] + Log[m + n])

I.e:
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \frac{1}{2}\left( \gamma -\operatorname{Ci}\left( 2n\pi \right) +\ln \left( 2n\pi \right) \right) & n=m\\
 \frac{1}{2}\left( \operatorname{Ci}\left[ \left( m-n \right) \pi \right] -\operatorname{Ci}\left[ \left( m+n \right) \pi \right] +\ln \left( \frac{m+n}{m-n} \right) \right) & n\ne m\\
\end{array} \right. 
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler constant, $\operatorname{Ci}$ is Cosine Integral function.

However, my ultimate goal is to know if it is possible to manually infer that result.

Comment: Hint: write the product of sines as a difference of cosines.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but some difficulties exist in further integration calculations, so I was not able to derive the final result manually.

Comment: I recommend editing details thereof into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: For $m=n$,
$$ \int_0^a\frac1{x}{\sin^2(\frac{n\pi x}{a})}dx=\int_0^a\frac{1-\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{a})}{2x}dx=\frac12(\gamma-Ci(2n\pi)+\ln(2n\pi)) $$
from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).
Do the same for the other.

Comment: @Richardo. Once you [perform the hinted-at operation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/), you'll recover an elementary integral that gives $I'(u)$. Then find $I(u)$ using what you know about the $\operatorname{Ci}$ function.

Comment: @Richardo. See the update.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When $m \neq n$
$$
\sin \left(\frac{n \pi}{a} x\right) \sin \left(\frac{m \pi}{a} x\right) =\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos \frac{(m-n) \pi}{a} x-\cos \frac{(m+n) \pi}{a} x\right]
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^a \frac{\cos \frac{(m-n) \pi x}{a} x}{x} d x-\int_0^a \frac{\cos \frac{(m+n) \pi}{a} x}{x} d x\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[C_{in}\left(\frac{m-n}{a} \pi x\right)-C_{in}\left(\frac{m+n}{a} \pi x\right)\right]_0^a\\& =\frac{1}{2}[C_{in}((m-n) \pi)-C_{in}((m+n) \pi)]
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the identity in [Cosine Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral),we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{2}\left[C_i((m-n) \pi)-\gamma-\ln (m-n) \pi-C_i((m+n) \pi)+\gamma+\ln (m+n)\right]\\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[C_i((m-n) \pi)-C_i((m+n) \pi)+\ln \left(\frac{m+n}{m-n}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$